# Can't see my NFT image in Wallet

Tags: contract-development, nft

I just crated a NFT and deployed it on Rinkeby to test it. I'm able to add my NFTs to wallets but I don't see the image I provided when minted it.

What could be the reason? The image was a small .png and it's provided with a URI to the contract. All I see is a generic image. The Same NFT image is not showing on opensea as well.

Comment: are you sure your `uri` point to json ? Then check you json format, [opensea use this](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards#section-metadata-structure) format.

Comment: I did not know that the uri had to point to a json. I point to a json that contains the URL of the image? i was inputing a plain url to an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `uri` need to point to a json file.

The json file works with IPFS but over HTTP they usually add the ID of the NFT at the end of the URI which the IPFS Json file will no handle.

Json file = IPFS (one file per NFT)   <-- Decentralize

API = HTTP request a DB by NFT ID. (one DB for all NFTs)  <-- Centralized

The Json format is used in all cases.

> This is the "ERC721 Metadata JSON Schema" referenced above.
>
> ```
> {
>    "title": "Asset Metadata",
>    "type": "object",
>    "properties": {
>        "name": {
>            "type": "string",
>            "description": "Identifies the asset to which this NFT represents"
>        },
>        "description": {
>            "type": "string",
>            "description": "Describes the asset to which this NFT represents"
>        },
>        "image": {
>            "type": "string",
>            "description": "A URI pointing to a resource with mime type image/* representing the asset to which this NFT represents. Consider making any images at a width between 320 and 1080 pixels and aspect ratio between 1.91:1 and 4:5 inclusive."
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

From the official [ERC721 EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md).

You can also check [opensea documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards#section-metadata-structure) which is more factual.

Comment: As to be served in the json format. From a Json file over IPFS or a API over HTTP. Because a json file wont handle the ID at the end of the uri. This is also platform specific but a good standard to follow would be OpenSea.

Answer (score 0):

This 3min tutorial explains how to view your NFT in your Metamask wallet: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/how-to-view-your-nft-in-your-wallet

Comment: It is not recommended to use link only answers. It is better if you include the main idea in the answer and only use the link to expand and provide more details.

Comment: The last time a checked you could only view NFT in Matask but you wont be able to transfer them. So it's pointless to dev NFT base on Metamask. If Metamask fully incorporate NFT they will also meet the standard.  And when i say you can view them in Metamask. Barely.